# What am I doing wrong when converting GAS to MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, avx, calling-convention

I have already taken care of the other various syntaxes like the alignment of the constants and addressing them (all of them are global) I have tried my best converting the GAS to be compatible with windows. but without luck my unit tests keep failing on windows... please do not suggest intrinsics, I must control the assembly in the final program for this routine. thank you!

```
eecos:
    vmovaps %xmm0, %xmm1 # xmm1 = xmm0

    vmovaps one(%rip), %xmm0 # initialize register to 1

    vmulps %xmm1, %xmm1, %xmm2 # x^2
    vmulps %xmm2, %xmm2, %xmm3 # x^4
    vmulps %xmm2, %xmm3, %xmm4 # x^6
    vmulps %xmm2, %xmm4, %xmm5 # x^8
    vmulps %xmm2, %xmm5, %xmm6 # x^10
    vmulps %xmm2, %xmm6, %xmm7 # x^12
    vmulps %xmm2, %xmm7, %xmm8 # x^14

    vmulps coef2(%rip), %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps coef4(%rip), %xmm3, %xmm3
    vmulps coef6(%rip), %xmm4, %xmm4
    vmulps coef8(%rip), %xmm5, %xmm5
    vmulps coef10(%rip), %xmm6, %xmm6
    vmulps coef12(%rip), %xmm7, %xmm7
    vmulps coef14(%rip), %xmm8, %xmm8

    vaddps %xmm2, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps %xmm3, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps %xmm4, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps %xmm5, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps %xmm6, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps %xmm7, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps %xmm8, %xmm0, %xmm0

    # setup rounding at the hundred thousanth place
    # hundred thousanth place should be stable enough for physics
    vmulps hunth(%rip), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vroundps $8, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmulps invhunth(%rip), %xmm0, %xmm0
    ret # return xmm0
```

what I have in MASM

```
eecos PROC FRAME
    .endprolog
    vmovaps xmm1, xmm0 ; xmm1 = xmm0

    vmovaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR one ; initialize register to 1

    vmulps xmm2, xmm1, xmm1 ; x^2
    vmulps xmm3, xmm2, xmm2 ; x^4
    vmulps xmm4, xmm3, xmm2 ; x^6
    vmulps xmm5, xmm4, xmm2 ; x^8
    vmulps xmm6, xmm5, xmm2 ; x^10
    vmulps xmm7, xmm6, xmm2 ; x^12
    vmulps xmm8, xmm7, xmm2 ; x^14

    vmulps xmm2, xmm2, XMMWORD PTR coef2
    vmulps xmm3, xmm3, XMMWORD PTR coef4
    vmulps xmm4, xmm4, XMMWORD PTR coef6
    vmulps xmm5, xmm5, XMMWORD PTR coef8
    vmulps xmm6, xmm6, XMMWORD PTR coef10
    vmulps xmm7, xmm7, XMMWORD PTR coef12
    vmulps xmm8, xmm8, XMMWORD PTR coef14

    vaddps xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps xmm0, xmm0, xmm3
    vaddps xmm0, xmm0, xmm4
    vaddps xmm0, xmm0, xmm5
    vaddps xmm0, xmm0, xmm6
    vaddps xmm0, xmm0, xmm7
    vaddps xmm0, xmm0, xmm8

    ; setup rounding at the hundred thousanth place
    ; hundred thousanth place should be stable enough for physics
    vmulps xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR hunth
    vroundps xmm0, xmm0, 8
    vmulps xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR invhunth
    ret ; return xmm0
; cosine subroutine here
eecos ENDP
END
```

The outputs (first is GAS)
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/R5vHC6kyfK/
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V2NgWmSqDN/

Comment: My first guess would be that the calling convention on Windows is different.  But I can't say for sure.  Can you make a [mcve] with a test harness so other's can debug this properly?

Comment: Also, please copy the output logs into the question.  Stack Overflow questions must be self-contained and should not rely on external paste services.

Comment: Does your GAS code work on Windows if you build it with MinGW binutils / gcc or clang?  I'd assume not if it's written for the x86-64 System V ABI's calling convention.  Agner Fog has a calling convention guide: https://www.agner.org/optimize/.  I'd recommend looking at compiler-generated code in the caller to see how it's passing args.

Comment: And BTW, AVX1 without FMA is only useful on a few machines, like Bulldozer (before Piledriver) and Sandy/Ivy Bridge (before Haswell).  And maybe AMD Jaguar.  If that's what you need; fine, otherwise you might consider accumulating with memory-source VFMA instructions.  Unless the longer latency of FMA vs. ADD on Haswell or Broadwell would be a bottleneck.  It's strange that you're doing a linear chain of additions instead of combining pairs of vectors to get some instruction-level parallelism in that step, unless that's strictly necessary for rounding.

Comment: turns out the issue was how I accessed global variables
things like XMMWORD PTR coef2, should have just been [coef2]
I can't seem to figure out how to edit the OP

as for the AVX, this is actually just vexed SSE (notice xmm registers instead of ymm) to prevent the overhead that occurs when the cpu hits a real AVX instruction